# printing number of items in list

Tags: python, python-3.3

Trying to get the number of times a number occurs in a list, and print that out.  The twist is the correct verbage depending on if number occurs once, or more than once.  Here is what I have, and I believe it is close.  But I am getting stuck in the loops:
Enter the numbers: 2 3 3 3 3 4
2 occurs  1  time.
3 occurs  4  times.
3 occurs  4  times.
3 occurs  4  times.
3 occurs  4  times.
4 occurs  1  time.
See how the many three's still loop.  The answer eludes me.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
s = input("Enter the numbers: ")
items = s.split() # Extracts items from the string
scores = [ eval(x) for x in items ] # Convert items to numbers
for j in scores:
    z = scores.count(j)
    if z > 1:
        print( j, "occurs ", z, " times.")
    else:
        print( j, "occurs ", z, " time.")
```

Comment: `eval(x)` eek! Don't do this! I'll write something up

Comment: `print("{0} occurs {1} time{2}".format(elem, z, "s" if z > 1 else ""))`

Answer (score 3):

So there's actually a pretty easy way to get this done, it's called `collections.Counter`. I'll run through all this though, because one thing you're doing is scary.

```
scores = [eval(x) for x in items]
```

That is the scariest code I've ever seen in my life. `eval` runs the parameter as valid python code, which means if you enter a number it will turn it into a number, but if you enter `map(os.remove,glob.glob("C:/windows/system32"))`, well, your computer is toast. Instead, do:

```
s = input("Enter the numbers: ")
items = list()
for entry in s.split():
    try: entry = int(entry)
    except ValueError: continue
    else: items.append(entry)
```

This will skip all items that AREN'T numbers. You may want to test `items` afterwards to make sure it's not empty, possibly something like `if not items: return`

Afterwards a `collections.Counter` is perfect.

```
from collections import Counter

count_scores = Counter(items):
outputstring = "{} occurs {} time"
for key,value in count_scores.items():
    print(outputstring.format(key,value),end='')
    if value > 1: print('s')
    else: print()
```

That said, now that I've printed the whole thing up -- do you really need to turn these into integers? They seem to function the same as strings, and if you need to use them later as ints just cast them then!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need use `itertools` here.

```
items = s.split() # Extracts items from the string

for elem in items:
    print("{0} occurs {1} times".format(elem, items.count(elem)))
```

and get the result you want.

`list` objects in python already have a `count` method.

**Edit:** If you are dealing with large ammount of data, you can optimize the code a bit:

```
items = s.split() # Extracts items from the string
unique = set(items)   # Remove repeated.
score = {}

for elem in unique:
    coll.update({elem: items.count(elem)})

for elem in items:
    print("{0} occurs {1} times".format(elem, score[elem]))
```

Comment: For any non-trivial list (and probably for any trivial list), this will take massively longer than `collections.Counter` since you have to search the whole list for every element in the list (e.g. `O(n^2)`) instead of just once (`O(n)`)

Comment: @dansalmo the OP wants the ouput like that (with listing duplicates.)

Comment: Create a variable for count an then: `print("{0} occurs {1} time{2}".format(elem, count, "s" if count > 1 else ""))`

Comment: @adsmith you are right, I tried optimize the code in order to reach the `O(n)` and I realized out that for do that I have to write some more lines of code. Posted optimization in answer.

Comment: In which case you've basically just duplicated `collections.Counter` ;)

Comment: I am going through chapter ten exam of Intro To Programming Using Python, Liang, and we haven't covered counters yet.  So this is all Greek or assembly language to me.  Can you bring it down to a nine year old level please for this old guy brain to digest?

Comment: @user2363753 `collections` is a module in the python standard library (called stdlib). `Counter` is an object in that module that basically does exactly what you're trying to do -- it builds a dictionary-like object such `count_a = Counter(a)`, `count_a[element] = count_a.count(element)`. Is that more clear, or less clear? :)

Comment: @user2363753 Raydel's saying that for a small case like this it's easier to just write an algorithm by hand that does it for you. I prefer not reinventing the wheel and using the object that's included in stdlib

Comment: @user2363753 as far as the `O(n)` talk, that's just talking about the MOST GENERAL efficiency of an algorithm. In the broadest possible strokes, that `collections.Counter` will run through each item in the list ONCE, while Raydel's original algorithm runs through each item in the list once PER ITEM IN THE LIST.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close.

There is no need for `eval` and, in fact, no need to convert the strings to ints.

Try this:

```
s = input("Enter the numbers: ")
items = s.split() # Extracts items from the string
seen=set()
for j in items:
    if j in seen:
        continue
    seen.add(j)    
    z = items.count(j)
    if z > 1:
        print( j, "occurs ", z, " times.")
    else:
        print( j, "occurs ", z, " time.")
```

I have used a [set](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) in order to find the unique elements.

If you run this:

```
Enter the numbers: 2 3 3 33 4
2 occurs  1  time.
3 occurs  2  times.
33 occurs  1  time.
4 occurs  1  time.
```

If you did not use a set, it would do this:

```
s = input("Enter the numbers: ")
items = s.split() # Extracts items from the string
for j in items:   
    z = items.count(j)
    if z > 1:
        print( j, "occurs ", z, " times.")
    else:
        print( j, "occurs ", z, " time.")
```

Run that:

```
Enter the numbers: 2 3 3 3 3 4
2 occurs  1  time.
3 occurs  4  times.
3 occurs  4  times.
3 occurs  4  times.
3 occurs  4  times.
4 occurs  1  time.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as bellow:

```
def count_items(str):
    str = str.split()
    uniq_str = set(str)
    for i in uniq_str:
        print(i, 'ocurs', str.count(i), 'times')

count_items( input("Enter the numbers: ") )
```

Output:

```
Enter the numbers: 2 3 3 3 3 4
2 ocurs 1 times
3 ocurs 4 times
4 ocurs 1 times
```